# matplotlib (Tkinker backend) crashing in multiprocessing.process - how to call XInitThreads

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiprocessing

This question relates to many other posts here that have the same error message when bringing up X-windows from within a Process - none seem to have a solution that works - but first the problem (as I found it using ipython 2.6):

I have a number of long processes and it makes sense to run them in parrallel using a seperate process in a single python session. These processes plot graphs using matplotlib.pyplot. However, when pyplot.show() or pyplot.figure() is called the process crashes the whole python session with the following error:

```
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this ia a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
python2.7: xcb_io.c:259: poll_for_event: Assertion '!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
Aborted
```

I was able to reproduce this error in a much more simple form from the ipython command line:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import multiprocessing as mp
def plot():
    pyplot.plot([1,2,3,4])
    pyplot.show() #this is the line it crashes on

# the next two lines are only needed if not iython --pyplot or you have not called pyplot.ion()
pyplot.plot([1,2,3,4]) 
pyplot.show() #close plot

p=mp.process.Process(target=plot)
p.start() #crash!!!!!
```

A check of `matplotlib.get_backend()` shows I'm running `TKAgg / Tkinker` Others with the same errors were also using `Tkinker` to make nice a gui.  It is also worth noting that I can run as many of my `plot` routines from seperate `ipython` sessions in different xterms with no problem. (Which given the `Process` command should create it's own namespace would seem to be the same thing).

So my question is, where (in python) do I find XIitThreads? How/when is it run? and fingers crossed it solves my problem (and some similar ones here).  I did find this post :[Threading: PyQt crashes with "unknown request in queue while dequeuing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31952711/threading-pyqt-crashes-with-unknown-request-in-queue-while-dequeuing) but this was for a PyQt4 backend (which I do not have and cannot install.)

EDIT - One warning - if you replace pyplot.show() with pyplot.show(block=False) then you will be left with a window that will not go away - could be an advantage of pyplot.save().

Also all attempts to find calls to xcb_io within Tkinter or matplotlib have failed - anyone know where those are?

Answer (score 0):

You may be happier if you replace .show() with `pyplot.save('foo.png')`, avoiding the attempt to pop up a new window. Then use a web browser to display *.png.

Comment: Not bringing up plots is a workaround (I could even run the browser from the python program) but given the error message tells me to run XInitThreads (and others have got the same errors creating a gui ) it might be nice to try it first.  The nice thing about brining up th eplots is users can zoom in to see details.

Comment: You have multiple processes. Is there any way you could devote a single process to `.show()`, and have worker bees send it completed plots?

Comment: Do those go through pickle? If not that could be tricky.  As far as I know anything sent back from a Process has to be pickled.  Could be a great solution.